# Calculate variables using equations then use the generated values to generate new one

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, tidyverse, zoo

It's hard to explain it but i'll take it step by step

Let's say I've 2 cars, one following another, and I've the speed of the lead car, and I want to calculate the distance between two of them, and we can calculate the distance using multiple equations, also I know the initial speed of the following car and the distance between two of them.

```
Following_Car_Speed = 13.68490 m/s
Distance = 17.024 m
Lead_Car_Speed = c(13.784896, 13.745834, 13.880556, 13.893577, 13.893577, 13.923959, 
13.945661, 13.919619, 13.897917, 14.002257, 14.002257, 13.980556, 
13.980556, 14.067536, 14.063195, 14.080556, 14.123959, 14.163021, 
14.236806, 14.167188)

Delta_Speed = Lead_Car_Speed[1]-Following_Car_Speed = 13.784896-13.68490 = 0.1

Gap <- 1.554 +  Following_Car_Speed*0.878- (Following_Car_Speed*Delta_Speed)/(2*sqrt(0.8418*0.8150))=
   1.554+ 13.68490*0.878- (13.68490*0.1)/(2*sqrt(0.8418*0.8150) = 12.74325
Acceleration <- 0.8418*(1-(Following_Car_Speed/29.2)^3.52-(Gap/Distance)^2)=0.3116923
```

Now I've calculated the acceleration, so I've to calculate the new speed of the following car .

```
Following_Car_Speed <- Following_Car_Speed + Acceleration*0.1
```

So now I've to calculate the new delta in speed between the lead and following car

```
Delta_Speed <- Lead_Car_Speed[2]-Following_Car_Speed
Distance<- Distance+(Delta_Speed[2]+Delta_Speed[1])/2*0.1
```

Then continue using the same equations till we end all the values of the following car.

It's easy to do this using For loops, but i want to get a more efficient way, I tried to use `dplyr`, but it's hard and I failed to get an answer.

So please help me.

---

```
myfun <- function(list, lcs,lcs2){
        ds <- lcs - list[[1]]
        Distance <- list[[1]]*D_Time - (list[[1]] * ds) / (2*sqrt(M_Acc*Com_Acc))
        if (Distance < 0|is.na(Distance)) {Distance <- 0}
        gap <-  Gap_J + Distance
        acc <- M_Acc * (1 - (list[[1]] / D_Speed)^Beta - (gap / list[[2]])^2)
        fcs_new <- list[[1]] + acc * 0.1
        ds_new <- lcs2- fcs_new
        di_new <- list[[2]]+(ds_new+ds)/2*0.1
        return(list(Speed = fcs_new,Distance = di_new))

} 

Generated_Data <- data %>%group_by(Driver,FileName)%>%
        mutate(Speed_Distance_Calibrated = accumulate2( .init = list(Filling_Speed[1],
                                                                     Filling_Range[1]),.x =  Lead_Veh_Speed_F,.y = Lead_Veh_Speed_F2, myfun)[-1])%>%ungroup()
```

I've add the lead of the lead_car_speed also i  wanted to use the new distance and new speed, so i made it into a list and put it into `.initla`

Comment: Hi, 
how does `Distance` get updated after the first iteration?

Comment: sorry it was my fault, i forgot writing about it, it must be updated, and it's the old distance plus the average between the new and old delta in speed multiplyed with 0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way using `accumulate` from the `purrr` package which is part of the tidyverse.

First I define a function `myfun` which updates the following_car_speed (fcs).

```
myfun <- function(fcs, lcs, di){
  ds <- lcs - fcs
  gap <-  1.554 + fcs*0.878 - fcs * ds / (2*sqrt(0.8418*0.8150))
  acc <- 0.8418 * (1 - (fcs / 29.2)^3.52 - (gap / di)^2)
  fcs_new <- fcs + acc * 0.1

  return(fcs_new)
} 

library(tidyverse)

tibble(lead_car_speed = c(13.784896, 13.745834, 13.880556, 13.893577, 13.893577, 13.923959, 
                          13.945661, 13.919619, 13.897917, 14.002257, 14.002257, 13.980556, 
                          13.980556, 14.067536, 14.063195, 14.080556, 14.123959, 14.163021, 
                          14.236806, 14.167188)) %>%
  mutate(following_car_speed = accumulate(lead_car_speed, myfun, .init = 13.68490, di = 17.024)[-1])^


# A tibble: 20 x 2
   lead_car_speed   following_car_speed
            <dbl> <dbl>
 1           13.8  13.7
 2           13.7  13.7
 3           13.9  13.8
 4           13.9  13.8
 5           13.9  13.8
 6           13.9  13.9
 7           13.9  13.9
 8           13.9  13.9
 9           13.9  13.9
10           14.0  14.0
11           14.0  14.0
12           14.0  14.0
13           14.0  14.0
14           14.1  14.1
15           14.1  14.1
16           14.1  14.1
17           14.1  14.1
18           14.2  14.1
19           14.2  14.2
20           14.2  14.2
```

If distance changes as well you can use `accumulate2` rather than `accumulate`.

Comment: May you update your answer please? i want to add the distance and get it as a new column like the following speed

Comment: I will try to update when I have time. For now checkout `accumulate2` or if your data is really large I would even suggest using the `rcpp` package instead.

Comment: I'm trying to know more about purrr and tidyverse, but it takes time to master it, also do you mean that i can do the same ussing Rcpp ?

Comment: also if you need more challanged questions, here's it 's https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57029872/using-nested-for-loops-in-fitness-function-in-genetic-algroithims-makes-it-too-s, it's the main question but no one answered it so i tried to make it into small ones

Comment: in calculating the new distance, i need to calculate the the new delta, but it depends on next row lead speed, what a mess .

Comment: Thanks alot Cett, please check my question again to update ur answer, i could solve this question using ur answer also my other question for GA

Comment: Cett, Is there a function like `accumulate2` more faster ?

Comment: C++ should be way faster. Checkout the rcpp package.

Answer (score 0):

Your operation depends on the iteration or some sort of recursion to be complete (due to possible `NA`, `Inf` etc) - seems like `for` or `while` is needed.

My alternative version is to break down the functions into easier unit for scaling and unit test for larger example or wrap around with another function calls .

I assume your var `Distance` is fixed for some reason and expected output is not provided, so I can't verify the functions completely.

```
Following_Car_Speed <- 13.68490
Lead_Car_Speed <- c(13.784896, 13.745834, 13.880556, 13.893577, 13.893577, 
                    13.923959, 13.945661, 13.919619, 13.897917, 14.002257, 
                    14.002257, 13.980556, 13.980556, 14.067536, 14.063195, 
                    14.080556, 14.123959, 14.163021, 14.236806, 14.167188)
Distance <- 17.024

#init
i <- length(Lead_Car_Speed)
Delta_Speed <- c(0.1, vector(mode = "numeric", length = i-1))
Gap <- c(12.74325, vector(mode = "numeric", length = i-1))
Acceleration <- c(0.3116923, vector(mode = "numeric", length = i-1 ))
Following_Car_Speed <- c(Following_Car_Speed, vector(mode="numeric", length = i-1 ))

cal.following.car.speed <- function(Following_Car_Speed, Acceleration){

  #calculate and return current following-car-speed: the i-th following-car-speed
  current.follow.car.speed <- Following_Car_Speed + Acceleration*0.1

  return(current.follow.car.speed)
}                                    

cal.delta.speed <- function(Lead_Car_Speed, following.car.speed){

  #calculate and return current delta speed: the i-th delta speed
  current.delta.speed <- Lead_Car_Speed - following.car.speed

  return(current.delta.speed)
}

cal.gap <- function(Following_Car_Speed, Delta_Speed){

  #calculate and return current gap: the i-th gap
  current.gap <- 1.554 + Following_Car_Speed*0.878 - (Following_Car_Speed*Delta_Speed)/(2*sqrt(0.8418*0.8150))

  return(current.gap)
}

cal.acceleration <- function(Following_Car_Speed, Gap, Distance){

  #calculate and return current acceleration: the i-th acceleration
  current.acceleration <- 0.8418*(1-(Following_Car_Speed/29.2)^3.52-(Gap/Distance)^2)

  return(current.acceleration)
}

#main
counter <- 1

while(counter != i){

  if(counter == 1) {counter = counter + 1} #skip 1st ith as we have init
  else{

    Gap[counter] <- cal.gap(Following_Car_Speed[counter-1], Delta_Speed[counter-1])  

    Acceleration[counter] <- cal.acceleration(Following_Car_Speed[counter-1], Gap[counter-1], Distance)

    Following_Car_Speed[counter] <- cal.following.car.speed(Following_Car_Speed[counter-1], Acceleration[counter])

    Delta_Speed[counter] <- cal.delta.speed(Lead_Car_Speed[counter], Following_Car_Speed[counter])

    counter = counter + 1
  }
}

cbind(Delta_Speed, Gap, Acceleration, Following_Car_Speed)
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, my problem in using any iteration is i've big data with simulation models, it'll be very slow if i use ur answer, Cett's answer is really helpful